# MailMessage System.Net.Mail.SmtpException, Error when trying to send email via C# form

Tags: c#, email

hi im stuck and keep getting errors when trying to setup a send email for.

here's my using.system:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

i then have this code in my send email button.

```
private void BtnEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {
                string to = "myEmail@gmail.com";
                string from = "myEmail@gmail.com";
                string subject = "Test email";
                string body = @"This is a test email";


                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, to, subject, body);
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("myEmail@gmail.com", "myPassword");
                client.Port = 587;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "\n\n" + ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.StackTrace, "Exception");
            }
        }
```

it looks like the exception is being through at the "client.send(mail);" line.

the catch exception message is: Failure sending mail.. System.Net.Mail.SmtpException.

any idea whats going wrong here?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you need understand the reason of this problem, you can use [SMTPDIAG](http://www.vsysad.com/2012/05/testing-smtp-server-on-server-2008-r2/) tool for this.

Try port 465 or 25  with SSL, because port 587 should be used with TLS.

Check Google documentation: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en.

Check your firewall and your ethernet firewall, ports may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because Google block these type of less secure mail. Check your mail that you have used in the code. If you have got one mail from google saying allow access to less secure app you can turn it on. now you will start receiving the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to you use `MailKit` library. Its great C# library for sending or retrieving emials.
For more informations or examples:
https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

This example shows how you can send email.

```
using System;

using MailKit.Net.Smtp;
using MailKit;
using MimeKit;

namespace TestClient {
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var message = new MimeMessage ();
            message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@friends.com"));
            message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "chandler@friends.com"));
            message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

            message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") {
                Text = @"Hey Chandler,

I just wanted to let you know that Monica and I were going to go play some paintball, you in?

-- Joey"
            };

            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

                // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

                client.Send (message);
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help, feel free to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Use port 465 for gmail. 587 will not work.

Comment: iv tried 465. the program just stops and does nothing. no exception, no errors or nothing..